# How to output data using NSJSONSerialization?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I'm trying to output some data using `NSJSONSerialization`using the code below.

This log statement works     `NSLog(@"publicData: %@", publicData);`
but then it crashes when I try to get the "description" of the dictionary        `NSLog(@"data: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"description"]);`

my error message: `unrecognized selector sent to instance. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...'`

I've included the `NSLog` output.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
                                                          URLWithString:@"http://******.com/api/feed"]];

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSArray *publicData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

NSLog(@"data from publicData: %@", publicData);
NSDictionary *dict;

for(int i=0; i<[publicData count];i++)
{
    dict= [publicData objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"data: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"description"]);

}


publicData: {
data =     (
            {
        address =             {
     address = "street address";
            city = cityname;
            lat = "42.000237034667";
            lng = "12.492805660226";
            province = provincename;
        };
        "category_id" = 20;
        description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum";
        id = 1;
        slug = "title-in-en";
        title = "title in En";
    },
            {
        address =             {
            address = "street address";
            city = cityname;
            lat = "42.000237034667";
            lng = "12.492805660226";
            province = provincename;
        };
        "category_id" = 20;
        description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum";
        id = 5;
        slug = "title-in-en";
        title = "title in En";
    },
```

thanks for any help

Comment: In your case, `publicData` is an NSDictionary with a single object for key "data", not an array. Access an `NSDictionary` with `objectForKey`, not `objectAtIndex`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I thought I was doing that though. Where "dict" is the dictionary and publicData is the nsarray. Is that incorrect? thanks! NSDictionary *dict;

for(int i=0; i<[publicData count];i++)
{
    dict= [publicData objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"data: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"description"]);

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I optimized a little the code provided by codeplasma and it's looking like this:

```
 NSDictionary *publicData =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response
                                                                options:0              
                                                                  error:&jsonParsingError];
    NSArray *objects = [publicData objectForKey:@"data"];
    for(NSDictionary *element in objects) {
       NSLog(@"the description is %@",[element objectForKey:@"description"]);
    }
```

Your publicData is `NSDictionary` not `NSArray`.

Comment: thanks but I'm getting an NSArray has no method 'objectForKey' error.

Comment: @hanumanDev can you post the full JOSN structure without your NSLog, maybe from your borwser :)

Comment: I just edited my question above and added the output from the browser. thanks for the help!

Comment: that worked perfectly! I was using an array instead of a dictionary. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work, but you should try to replace your for loop with this:

```
for(int i=0; i<[[publicData objectForKey:@"data"] count];i++)
{
    dict= [[publicData objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"data: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"description"]);

}
```